# is it mandatory all inputs to use fieldset and leyend tags in order to satisfy the point WCAG 1.3.1

Tags: asp.net, forms, tags, wcag2.0

First of all, as always say, sorry about my english, and my ignorance, sure there are a lot of misunderstanding about I suppose I know.

I've got a big asp.net site (uses master pages, handlers, etc.)and I need my site to compliance to WCAG 2.0. In order to do that I'm trying
to pass all failures especified for WCAG 2.0 AA but after read the H44 technique I realize the forms in my aspx pages don't using fieldset and leyend tags 
for my forms, here is where my question arises:

is it mandatory all input controls to use fieldset and leyend tags in order to satisfy the point 1.3.1?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory that all input controls use the fieldset and legend tags, but if you have a group of related input controls then you should use the fieldset and legend tags so the user understands that the fields are related and the user can see how they are related with the content of the legend tag. Also, you should be using label tags on your inputs to identify the field label.

See "[H71: Providing a description for groups of form controls using fieldset and legend elements" for more info on fieldset and legend](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H71.html)".